# Does anyone know if there is a term to describe the following process?

Tags: kinetic-theory

Taken from Giancoli 7th edition:

The random (thermal) velocities of molecules in a cell affect cloning. When a
bacterial cell divides, the two new bacteria have nearly identical DNA. Even if
the DNA were perfectly identical, the two new bacteria would not end up behaving
in exactly the same way. Long protein, DNA, and RNA molecules get bumped into
different shapes, and even the expression of genes can thus be different. Loosely held parts of large molecules such as a methyl group can also be knocked
off by a strong collision with another molecule. Hence, cloned organisms are not
identical, even if their DNA were identical. Indeed, there can not really be
genetic determinism.

I'm aware of different biological processes that can affect gene expression but this is random kinetic motion!

Comment: Are you looking for "stochastic process" or something more specific?

Comment: Something more specific. For example, genetic drift might produce similar outcomes but operates on populations, and I've always associated epigenetic changes with other mechanisms. Perhaps it's just a special case of epigenetic modification. I never heard about in my biology courses and just thought someone here might be familiar with it considering it involves kinetic theory.